# I'm experiencing a long response time in postman during use middleware

Tags: node.js, postman, mern

**Hi friends, I'm experiencing a long response time in postman when I add middleware in the routers**.

[image]

*****I was tried to check the middleware, but nothing have an error and also the postman request don't reach after middleware to my router controller. please help me*****

---

***here is my middleware***

```
app.use('/api/v1/exercise',authenticationMiddleware,exerciseRoute);
```

***Here is my router***

```
router.route('/').get(getAllExercise)
```

***Here is my router controller***

```
const getAllExercise =async (req,res) => {
          
     res.status(200).send(`Hi `)
}
```

Comment: Make sure that your application working without an error.

Answer (score 1):

**sorry friends, I just forget to add next() function in my last line of middleware**

```
    const middleware = (req,res,next) =>{
  
   next()

  }
```

**I hope it's helpful for someone like me. thankyou.**

*my apologies for anyone feeling wasting time on this question.*

Answer (score 0):

move the middleware inside router and remove it from app.use() :

```
router.route('/').get(authenticationMiddleware, getAllExercise)
```